# How to replicate and sync a MySQL to graph database

Tags: mysql, neo4j, graph-databases, database-replication, oracle-golden-gate

I need to replicate and continuously sync a MySQL database to a graph database, to further query and analyze data from an eCommerce application.

Came across [DZone Article](https://dzone.com/articles/oracle-rdbms-neo4j-fully-sync-relational-and-graph) which talks about syncing data between oracle and Neo4J. They are using Oracle GoldenGate and Apache Kafka for this.

However, I have a few questions on how this would be implemented -

1. What about the graph data model? Can I generate graph data model from existing RDBMS data model? Are there any open source ETL solutions to map data models between source and target?
2. The RDBMS data model may change as part of new features. How to keep data models in sync between a source RDBMS and target graph database?
3. Are there any other approaches to make this work?

I'm fairly new to SQL to NoSQL replication. Any inputs?

Comment: Hi, did you try something? We now have similar use case...

Comment: @JosMac I'm currently trying Neo4J ETL tool to extract and map MySQL database schema to graph. As DZone article mentioned in the question, next step would be to integrate GoldenGate and a Kafka to sync changed data to Neo4J.

Do you have a simpler approach in mind?